# Get inner text of a nearby <h3> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the inner text/value of a `<h3>` with the class `"grid-block__title"` that (to my knowledge?) is currently above the element I need to start on (`<p>` with id `addToCartMessageParagraph`). How can I do this correctly? My abbreviated markup looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="grid-block__title">...</h3>
  <h3 class="grid-block__description">...</h3>
  <h3 class="grid-block__description">...</h3>
  <form>
    <select>...</select>
    <span>...</span>
    <button>...</button>
    <input>...</input>
    <input>...</input>
    <p id="addToCartMessageParagraph" class="js-item-added js-hidden ...">...</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

I've tried..

- `$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').closest('h3[class="grid-block__title"]').val();` (*undefined*)
- `$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').closest('h3').val();` (*undefined*)
- `$(this).find('.js-item-added').closest('h3').val();` (*undefined*)
- I believe I also tried the `.prev('h3')` command and I got *not available* in the Chrome debugger.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: `$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').parent().closest('h3.grid-block__title"').text()` might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the closest `form` ancestor element, and then get the previous `h3` element using the `.prevAll()` or `.siblings()` method (since the `form`/`h3` elements are siblings):

```
$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').closest('form').siblings('h3.grid-block__title').text();
```

or:

```
$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').closest('form').prevAll('h3.grid-block__title').first().text();
```

The reason your attempt(s) weren't working was because the `h3` element isn't an ancestor of the `#addToCartMessageParagraph` element. The `.closest()` method will traverse up the DOM tree and filter through the ancestor elements. The solution is to select the closest `form` ancestor and then get the sibling `h3` element (since the `h3`/`form` elements are siblings).

---

Alternatively, if the wrapper `div` element has a class (such as `.wrapper`), then you could simply traverse up the DOM and select it and then select the descendant `h3` element:

```
$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').closest('.wrapper').find('h3.grid-block__title').text();
```

of cousrse, if it's always the closest `div` ancestor, you could just select it based on the element type:

```
$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').closest('div').find('h3.grid-block__title').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to find the closest div and traverse from there as follows.

```
$('#addToCartMessageParagraph').closest('div').find('h3.grid-block__title').text();
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/d8ktmbmp/